# Function Pointers vs calling cout directly

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm working on a C++ class assignment and I'd like some input. I'm not looking for 'help' with my assignment as much as I use class assignments as an excuse to practice writing 'good' code, and I'm debating between two solutions to the current problem I'm working on.

I'm storing roughly 4000 values in an STL map. One of the features of this program is to print out every value in my map. I have a class called 'driver' that handles the internal logic of the application and holds a reference to the map. I have a separate class for user interface.

What I was going to do was pass a function pointer to my driver, which iterates through the map and calls back to the function in my UI class. Would this be a bad idea performance wise at roughly 4000 function calls? Should I bite the bullet and simply call cout while iterating? I hesitate to do this because I'm trying to keep my user interface completely isolated from my program logic and data. I know in the end it really doesn't matter as it's just a class assignment, but assuming hypothetically this is code I would want to maintain in the long run, what would the 'best' practice be here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** don't worry about it. 4k indirect calls is not a big deal. If you're worried about performance, do the following:

- code it up the easy way
- performance good? done.
- performance bad? use a profiler, like [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html), to find out why, then fix only what is is needed

Remember that 'premature optimization is the root of all evil.'

**Slightly longer version:** You could define your call back as follows:

```
template <typename IteratorType>
void my_multi_callback(iterator start, iterator end);
```

Then, the driver can just pass the appropriate `map` iterators (describing the range of things to print). The callback then performs the output for every element, so you're avoiding the repeated indirect function calls.

Comment: Thanks! Your slightly longer version is definitely what I'm going to try, that's a very nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably pass in an iterator. When you want to print the data to `cout`, pass an `ostream_iterator`. Later, if you want to (for example) copy the data from the map to a vector or some such, you can just pass a different iterator (in that case, probably a back_inserter).

This gives flexibility, but since the iterator is basically a functor, it also (usually) eliminates the overhead of calling the function via a pointer as well. When you're copying to standard output that probably doesn't matter (the time to call a function through a pointer is pretty small compared to the time to actually write to the stream), but when/if you copy to somewhere else, the speed is likely to matter more.

Comment: +1 for sensible solution that is the exact inverse of my own (I assert also sensible) solution :)

Comment: @phooji: Yes, pretty much the same thing in opposite directions. I'd agree that yours is perfectly sensible as well.

Comment: I've been investigating both solutions, and with this one there seems to be an issue with using ostream_iterators with a map because the map iterator returns a pair. Is there any graceful way around this issue?

Comment: @sensae: There's not really an issue -- an `ostream_iterator` writes things via `operator<<`, so you need to define `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, std::pair<key, value> const &);`.

Comment: Very oddly, looking at my errors more closely, it seems to be complaining no match for operator=, not operator<<. Googling all the errors seem to involve operator<<, and when I fully defined operator<< it had no effect.

Comment: @sensea: For this solution, the output iterator basically replaces your callback function. So you should consider very carefully what you want to output -- if you just care about the name, then you could output the name/value pairs as a single string, for example. If you wanted a reference (e.g., for the GUI version of this), then you would have to define some `<<` overload as Jerry suggested.

Comment: I understand how the solution works and is a replacement for a callback function, but unfortunately I can't get it to compile, gcc complains no match for 'operator=' in ostream_iterator. I apologize if I'm simply being dense, but Googling has not helped - everybody with an issue has an issue with operator<<. I probably just don't know the nuances of C++ syntax well enough and I appreciate your attempting to explain this to me. This definitely isn't critical, as I can always just directly call cout, I just enjoy these elegant solutions. :)